# Android: How can I change title in action bar, but keep app name the same?

Tags: java, android, titlebar

How can I keep the name of my app the same, but change what the title of the main activity is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTitle("Hello StackOverflow"); worked

Answer (score 1):

Just set `android:label` for each `Activity` on your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: in onCreate() method or if you are using fragment you need to put getActivity.getActionBar().setTitle(title);

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the title at compile time you have to use android:label for each Activity on your AndroidManifest.xml. But if you want to change the title at runtime then you have to use getActionBar().setTitle("title");.